# AdMob -Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, admob

```
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport (8.9.1)
Firebase (8.9.1):
Xcode -Version 12.4 (12D4e)
iPad Simulator -12.9 inch 3rd Generation
```

There is a Flutter thread on this problem [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/363)

I'm having this issue with banner ad testAdID units when rotating on an iPad to landscape.
For example in Portrait the test ad shows and works fine but once I rotate the iPad to landscape I get

> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.

The odd thing is once I rotate back to portrait the ad appears.

This process is non-stop. The ad always shows in portrait but nothing shows in landscape with the same above error message

I looked in `Target` > `Build Settings` > `All` > `Other Linker Flags` and it was already set to `Obj-C`

[image]

code:

```
// called in ViewDidLoad
func initializeAdMob() {
    
    let adMobKey = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    
    bannerView.adUnitID = adMobKey
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.delegate = self
    
    let adSize = GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(frame.size.width)
    bannerView.adSize = adSize
    
    view.addSubview(bannerView)
    bannerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    bannerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true

    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
}
```

Comment: I ran into the same not long ago. It only seems to happen in test environments. I don’t have any issues with my published app. If you run it on release mode and with you use the actual id it should work. The odd thing too was that if I let it sit for a bit the dummy adapter message appears every so often but if u wait long enough it might actually show an ad and then you start getting the dummy message again. I think it is an admob server thing and every so often you get a dummy ad. Try using print on the adSize in the is presenting method of the delegate, I was getting height zero on it too.

Comment: @loremipsum thanks for the help. Gimme a few hrs and I’ll test in release withy real unit and see what happens. If it works I’ll come back here and let you know. Btw I think you should post this as an answer instead of a comment. If it works I’ll accept it. TTYL ✌

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only seems to happen in test environments.

I don’t have any issues with my published app.

If you run it on `release` mode and with the actual `id` it should work.

The odd thing to was that if I let it sit for a bit the dummy adapter message appears every so often (like it is asking for a new ad) and if you wait long enough it might actually show an ad and then you start getting the dummy message again.

I think it is an Admob server thing and every so often you get a dummy ad.

Also, try using `print` on the `adSize` in the `bannerViewWillPresentScreen` of the delegate, I was getting `height = 0` on there too. When I was using `fluid` as the size. So the banner was there but you can't see it because the height is zero.

Comment: You was correct, I just needed to use my real AdUnitId and then it worked. I was able to do it with my `Build Configuration` still in `Debug` too.  The adSize printing was a great benefit. For some reason `bannerViewWillPresentScreen` didn't get called so I added **print(bannerView.adSize)** to `bannerViewDidReceiveAd`, `bannerViewDidRecordImpression`, and `bannerView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: Error)`. Thanks for the help! Happy Coding!!! :)

Comment: @LanceSamaria I’m glad it helped. Remember to not keep your id in the test environment. Your admob could get flagged for this and suspended google wants you to test with the test ids

Comment: Yeah definitely, I just tried it to rotate the iPad to see what happens. After your answer worked I switched it back to the testId

Answer (score 0):

I use Ionic adMob plugin @capacitor-community/admob
and constantly was getting this com.google.DummyAdapter for reward video always until I removed isTesting=true, default =false  and switch from google testing adId 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313' to real one

```
RewardAdOptions{
 adId: 'real add id'
 //isTesting: true
}
```

await AdMob.prepareRewardVideoAd(options);